# Show customer details on WooCommerce Thankyou page even if not registered

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, for logged in users the Thankyou (order-received) page does show the customer details like the name, address and e-mail, but **nothing when customers are not registered.**

How can I ensure that non registered users can see their details on the Thankyou (order-received) page when the payment is successfully finished, just like registered users?

Why the customer details doesn't show up on the Thankyou (order-received) page for non registered users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this behavior for non logged users with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'adding_customers_details_to_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function adding_customers_details_to_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Only for non logged in users
    if ( ! $order_id || is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); // Get an instance of the WC_Order object

    wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-customer.php', array('order' => $order ));
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

> May be the fact that customer info doesn't show up is for **security reasons**, as this info is **not really protected** the same way than for logged in users (registered users).

Comment: thank you mate! It works!!

How do you know this hook? Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @CalvinK On woocommerce templates `checkout/thankyou.php` you will see this hook. The template `order/order-details-customer.php` is the one used for customer details output *(needing the $order object to work in a correct way)*… that's all :)

Comment: hi @LoicTheAztec this works only for me when it's a logged in user but if it's a guest user it's not loading the template. any idea?

Comment: @nyjn24 Normal this is done for logged in users only… so just remove `|| is_user_logged_in()`…

Comment: Had the same issue guys! I have just implemented the above code and it works like a charm! Best Regards!