# Calling Template to offer same display as other pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am building a Woocommerce shop. As you will know, when adding products they are then assigned to categories... when I view each category, the products are displayed in a generic fashion... IE 12 products per page over XX Pages...

Currently, when creating a new page in wordpress, it does not allow me to select the template which woocommerce uses to display my categories.

I am trying to find a way to create my own template which calls the layout from the template all my other categories uses, so that I can then use it on any custom product pages I make whilst keeping the website uniform

currently when I use the featured products shortcode, It displayes how ever many products I ask it to, It does not break it doen into pages and I cann ot use the filters that I use on the other pages.

I have tried...

```
get_template()
```

and

```
template_loader()
```

Functions but nothing seems to work.

I am new to web design but seem to be picking up fast but cannot figure for the life of me how to call a template layout into my own page.

I am also unsure what template woocommerce uses to display its category items, I have searched google and seem to get conflicting answers.

any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Have a look to dedicated Woocommerce [`wc_get_template()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_template.html) … and a usage on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336029/show-customer-details-on-woocommerce-thankyou-page-even-if-not-registered/47338937#47338937

Comment: @LoicTheAztec. Thank you for your reply, you have helped with a few of my questions and I am very grateful. I have looked at https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_template.html but in all honesty, I have no idea how to interprate it. As mentioned above, I am still learning, self taught but still a lot of learning to do :-)

Comment: When you use this function, you need to give: 1°) in first argument the woocommerce path of the template to include (like in my linked example)… 2°) the variables you want to pass from your hooked function to the template (like if the template needs the `WC_Order` object `$order` you will use `array( 'order' => $order );` just like in my linked example (but the variable you pass has to be defined in your code)… I hope that is a bit more clear for you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have tried and appear to have got the correct theme loaded. My problem now is when I include the shortcode to show the products, The products either appear above or below the template, depending on where in the script i position the shortcode. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @LoicTheAztecThank you. I may contact you later if possible? I have ammende my question to try and make it clearer what I am after. I have seen the `taxonomy-product_cat.php`  which calls template using `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );` do you know if this should work? I have tried but cant seem to get anything from it. My understanding is that it is `archive-products.php` that I want to replicate from my template